# diffutil sort arrayadapter position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

We are trying to sort an ArrayList that contains data from sqlite database.
I can sort the list with this added to the query " ORDER BY " + Col_IDBG + " DESC 
Which works as desired except the position data in the RecyclerAdapter is not in sync with the DESC ordering. So next we used Collections.reverse(dbList); which works but once again the RecyclerAdapter is not in sync with the reverse order.

We have narrowed the problem to the RecylerAdapter code below.
We would like to know how to use DiffUtil to keep the position in sync with the sort method?

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView station;
    public TextView rowid;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        rowid = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvROWID);
        station = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvWEBSITE);
        // Attach a click listener to the entire row view
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override // When an item in ListActivity is touched (selected) the RecyclerView has
    //  a OnClickListener attached in the above Code that implements the method below
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intentN = new Intent(context,BuyGasDetailActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt("POSITION",getAdapterPosition());
        extras.putString("FROM_LIST_ACTIVITY","false" );
        intentN.putExtras(extras);
        context.startActivity(intentN);
    }
}
```

The position is passed to DetailActivity to view all data associated with the item in the ListActivity with the intentN

Comment: I am sorry your question is unclear, are you asking about how to implement a DiffUtils for your adapter?

Comment: @MohamedHamdaoui Yes we would like to use DiffUtil to keep the position in sync with the dbList. OR any other method to permit the dbList to be in DESC order The issue is when the dbList is in DESC order the item selected is the wrong item

Comment: Does the order of the items in your database change during runtime?

Comment: @MohamedHamdaoui NO once the items in the table are inserted the query keeps the dbList in DESC order by ID

Comment: What do you mean by "Keep" ? there must be a moment when it is executed, why aren't you using that moment to set your adapter and the data will be ordered!

Comment: @MohamedHamdaoui We tried that with this Collections.reverse(dbList); and as stated it sorts the dbList but the position data is not in sync with the DESC or reverse sort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160456/discussion-between-mohamed-hamdaoui-and-james-duh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple to solve you just need to use the Collections.reverse(dbList); in TWO places the RecyclerAdapter and the DetailActivity 
Here is the code in the RecyclerAdapter

```
    @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Collections.reverse(dbList);
    return dbList.size();
}
```

and here is the code in the DetailActivity inside the onCreate method

```
    dbList = helper.getDataFrom_BUY_GAS_TABLE();
    Collections.reverse(dbList);
```

Tested and works great

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `SortedList` which is more efficient. `SortedList` is available in Support library V7 (`android.support.v7.util`). Based on the documentation:

> It keeps items ordered using the SortedList.Callback.compare(Object, Object) method and uses binary search to retrieve items.

It more efficient and provides better control over add, insert & delete in sorted list. All you have to do is switch our list to SortedList in our adapter and override 3 adapter callback methods: `compare()`, `areContentsSame()` and `areItemsSame()`. You can find more details about its usage [here](https://medium.com/bakedroid/android-sortedlist-explained-2def504e46d7).